# no difference between runlevel 3 and 5 in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, runlevel

From the exercises in chapter 3 from *Introduction to Linux*:

> Which services run in graphical mode that don't run in text mode?

So I tried:

```
diff <(ls -l rc3.d/) <(ls -l rc5.d/)
```

Ran in the terminal in the /etc directory but according to the output (there is no output) there is no difference between both, which I don't understand. Can someone clarify?

Furthermore when I try changing runlevels from 5 to 3 by issuing:

```
sudo telinit 3
```

from the terminal, the screen turns black and freezes. There is no response to any input from the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.3.3.1), by default there's no difference between runlevels 2 to 5 and runlevel customization is up to the system administrator:

> By default `update-rc.d` will start services in each of the multi-user state runlevels (2, 3, 4, and 5) and stop them in the halt runlevel (0), the single-user runlevel (1) and the reboot runlevel (6). The system administrator will have the opportunity to customize runlevels by simply adding, moving, or removing the symbolic links in `/etc/rcn.d` if symbolic links are being used, or by modifying `/etc/runlevel.conf` if the `file-rc` method is being used.